# Enable local database caching for MySQL in VS 2010

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am following these walkthroughs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488233.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384472.aspx

to set up a local database cache in my wpf application, however, none of them works for MySQL database :( I downloaded the connector for mysql, but it does not appear in the list when trying to add local database cache. If I try the other walkthrough and use the data source configuration wizard, I can connect to mySQL database, but when I select the table, the "Enable local database caching" does not appear (it does for mssql db). Any help??

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: It's a MSSQL-specific technology. You are going to have to roll your own framework, or use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753 and write some code.

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, that's bad :( any idea,how much it requires using the ms sync framework ?

Comment: You could use SQL Express, which has support for it. MS Sync Framework is free; and from what I hear: easy to use.